# How to check if a number is less or equal in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i was trying to check in a switch statement if a number was greater or equal to a different number, however, i ran into an issue, where it returns undefined.

```
const getBalance = (userid) => {
  const balance = 1000000;

  switch (balance) {
    case balance <= 0:
      return "1";
    case balance <= 500:
      return "2";
    case balance <= 1000:
      return "3";
  }
};
```

How could i solve this issue ?

Comment: Is there some logic in the thresholds? Like are they multiples of 500? Or could they be quite unrelated, like `balance <= 236`?

Comment: @trincot They are unrelated

Comment: Switch statement is not meant to do this, You can make it work, but it makes no sense. Use if statements

Comment: What’s with not using a simple `if`/`else if`/`else` block?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const getBalance = (userid) => {
  const balance = userid;

  switch (true) {
    case balance <= 0:
      return "1"
    case balance <= 500:
      return "2"
    case balance <= 1000:
      return "3"
    default:
      return "4"
  }
}

console.log(getBalance(10))
console.log(getBalance(100))
console.log(getBalance(500))
console.log(getBalance(600))
console.log(getBalance(1000))
console.log(getBalance(1200))
```

but it is not an elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the default from switch statement

```
 switch (balance) {
case balance <= 0:
  return "1";
case balance <= 500:
  return "2";
case balance <= 1000:
  return "3";
default: 
 return "4";
```

}

After altering your method you should get "4" as return value

Comment: also don't need to repeat `balance` at every `case` line

Comment: @Aaron that is not true, this is not a typical switch with values, so it needs repetition unfortunately

Comment: I tried this, but the issue is, when i sent balance to 100, it still returned 4 for some reason

Comment: so how is my answer different form one posted ? why the -1

Answer (score 1):

You use `switch` in a wrong way: the `case` expressions are booleans, which never match the value of `balance`. You could use `findIndex` instead:

```js
const getBalance = (balance) => {
    return [0, 500, 1000, Infinity].findIndex(lim => balance <= lim) + 1;
}

console.log(getBalance(-10));
console.log(getBalance(100));
console.log(getBalance(500));
console.log(getBalance(600));
console.log(getBalance(1000));
console.log(getBalance(1200));
```

Comment: Imo that's the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

the conditions you have applied are not completely true, if you enter 10, its true for both <=500 and <=1000
Make your conditions like, < 0, > 0 && <=500, 500 > %% <=1000